# Word VBA - select the rest of the word from Find

Tags: vba, find, ms-word

I try to use Find.FindText in Word VBA to find the first few letters of a word, then select the rest of that word. For example, if I have:
"Hello , AB-1234-123 check"

I would find "AB-" then select the rest of the word to get "AB-1234-123". I cannot use space as my MoveEndUntil("  ") because, sometimes, the word ends with a period.

So far, my code is

```
SearchString = "AB-"
With Rng.Find
Do While .Execute(FindText:=SearchString, Forward:=True) = True
         Rng.MoveEndUntil (" ")
         MsgBox (Rng.Text)
Loop
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use `MoveEndUntil`. If you look at the Help topic for the method, you'll see that the first parameter, named *CSet*, can hold multiple characters. So it can look for a space as well as a period, a comma, a semicolon, etc.

While testing your code, it also came to my attention that, as it stands, it will go into a continuous loop - always finding only the first instance. So I've taken care of that with the `Collapse` method so that the next Find sequence starts immediately after the last "found" range.

```
Dim rng As word.Range
Dim SearchString As String

Set rng = ActiveDocument.content
SearchString = "AB-"
With rng.Find
    Do While .Execute(findText:=SearchString, Forward:=True) = True
      rng.MoveEndUntil (" .,;!")
      MsgBox rng.Text
      rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have another quick question, if the word end with a line break, can I make rng.MoveEndUntil(" .,;vbNewLine) so it can include line break?

Comment: What happens when you try? And I'd tend to try with Chr(13) instead of vbNewLine...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can select the found word portion, then expand it to the whole word?

`Selection.Expand Unit:=wdWord`